# I want to position my element one at start and one at end of the div in react using tailwind css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to position my element one at start(left most corner) and one at end(right most corner) of the div in react using tailwind css
How to do it in react using tailwind css ?

I tried this

```
const Header = () => {
   return (
     <div className='flex flex-row border-4 border-indigo-600 h-12 justify-content'>
       <div className='justify-start'>
           first element
        </div>
      <div className='justify-end'>
         second element
      </div>
    </div>
```

)
}

Comment: Which left and right corner? Rectangles have two left and two right corners.

Comment: top most corner and what if i have to place just at right end of rectangle

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-between` class basically it sets the flex **justify content** property to

`justify-content: space-between;`

New code should be :

```
<div className='flex flex-row justify-between border-4 border-indigo-600 h-12'>
    <div>
       first element
    </div>
    <div>
       second element
    </div>
</div>
```